# SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

Im trying to install [Webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack) but it keeps giving me the same warning over and over and still webpack it's not installed in my project . It is an exiting project that im working with. I tried so many commands like

> npm install --no-optional
>
> npm install --global webpack
>
> npm install --save-dev webpack
>
> npm install i -g --save-dev webpack webpack-dev-server
>
> npm i -D webpack
>
> yarn add webpack --dev

I tried deleting the node_modules on my project and installing them again but it still gives me the same warning

> SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

and the webpack is not installed.

Comment: That warning shouldn't prevent webpack from installing. As it says, its an optional dependency. There's likely something else going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I had a problem with versions so i fixed it like this :
>   I installet [WebPack Installer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebPackTaskRunner)
>
> Node-sass should support NodeJs version look which nodeJs version supports node-sass :
>       [Link](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/)
>
> Delete **node_modules** folder in project and install again **"npm install"** in cmd
>
> **npm uninstall node-sass**
>   **npm install node-sass@4.12.0** --- or the version which is supported for your NodeJs version
>
> npm rebuild node-sass

This Fixed my problem which was with different versions of NodeJs and Node-sass

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you can use yarn

```
npm i yarn
yarn install
```